# After a user clones a repo, does the user have to reconfigure to use the .gitmessage.txt?

Tags: git, github

I use my own commit message template. That template file name is `.gitmessage.txt`.
The template file is pushed to the GitHub remote repository.
In my local laptop, I have configured like this;

```
$ git config --local commit.template .gitmessage.txt
```

After cloning, I want the user to use my template if the user tries to commit.

If a user clones my repository to his or her desktop, will that user have to type the above command to use my template? Or, after cloning, will Git use that template file without typing the configure command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git pull/push commits, blobs and tags but not configuration. So yes, your users have to run this command after cloning the repo. Include instructions into your README.